# How to poll / make progress without blocking in async rust

Tags: rust, boost-asio, rust-tokio

In C++ with boost asio, you can make progress on an asynchronous context by calling `io_context.run()` (blocking) or `io_context.poll()` (non-blocking). It seems in rust, `await` behaves similarly to asio `run`. I would like to understand what the rust version of asio `poll` is.

Suppose I have some async function which loops forever. The following code work as expected:

```
use tokio::time::Duration;

async fn some_async_function() {
    loop {
        println!("Before await");
        tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(2)).await;
        println!("After await");
    }
}

#[tokio::main(flavor = "current_thread")]
async fn main() {
    let local = tokio::task::LocalSet::new();
    local.spawn_local(some_async_function());
    local.spawn_local(some_async_function());
    local.await;
}
```

I would like to be able to rewrite the main function in the following way:

```
#[tokio::main(flavor = "current_thread")]
async fn main() {
    let local = tokio::task::LocalSet::new();
    local.spawn_local(some_async_function());
    local.spawn_local(some_async_function());
    loop {
        local.poll(); // make progress on async tasks without blocking
        
        // otherwise, execute some logic like processing a synchronous queue of messages
    }
}
```

Latency is important. I would like the code to remain single threaded.

I am uncertain if I am using `LocalSet` correctly, so I am happy to change that part if necessary.

Comment: You probably don't need thread local tasks, and therefore should prefer `tokio::spawn()`. If you want single-threading, consider using a single-threaded runtime.

Comment: Are you sure you need to do the work between polls? Spawning three tasks, two for the async and one for the work, seems better.

Comment: I feel like this is a weak version of an XY problem - the actual problem (to me) seems to be *'execute some logic like processing a synchronous queue of messages'*. Things like synchronous message queues should be wrapped in `async` abstractions, so they don't require busy polling. Busy polling is one of those things that are incompatible with an async program.

Comment: Async programs are meant to be **event driven** - meaning, everything sleeps until something happens. No loop that continuously polls something. Of course there might be things that happen periodically, but then there should be some kind of time event (like an async wait in a loop) that triggers it.

Comment: *"It seems in rust, `await` behaves similarly to asio `run`."* - this is incorrect, those two are completely different concepts. See what [`tokio_main`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/attr.main.html#using-current-thread-runtime) actually resolves to - the equivalent of `io_service::run()` is closer to [`Runtime::block_on()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/runtime/struct.Runtime.html#method.block_on). Rust's `await` is closer to C++20's [`co_await`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines#co_await).

Comment: what's the equivalent of `io_service::poll()`? that's the question I'm primarily interested in

Comment: You can [`poll`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/future/trait.Future.html#tymethod.poll) a future…

Comment: I don't think an equivalent of `io_service::poll` exists in tokio - tokio event loops always run to completion (from what I can tell). You also aren't meant to use the event loop manually much - different to C++, in Rust it's intended that the `main` function itself is already inside of an async context (`async fn main()`). So things like `poll`/`run` already happened in the background, inside of the `tokio::main` macro.

Comment: regarding the XY problem - this might be the case, but it seems strange to me to wrap the synchronous component into async abstractions, and (a) possibly pay some performance penalty (b) lose some control over ordering, e.g. maybe I'd like to deplete the queue before performing any more async work

Comment: @Jmb I think you misunderstand his intentions here - he is talking about a single threaded async context, that needs to be polled periodically in order to progress, because the `main` itself is **outside** of the context. That's at least my understanding; that doesn't map to how `async` reactors usually work in Rust/tokio, though.

Comment: @yoyoy That's not how tokio's async works - you should **never** block the event queue. If you have something blocking, you should spawn it on a different thread with `spawn_blocking`. Intentionally blocking the event queue for some reason is an antipattern. Instead, you should set up your task dependencies correctly.

Comment: I expect depleting the queue to be extremely fast and essentially non-blocking - it's more like e.g. some async function adds two events to the queue, and I'd like to prioritize processing both of those over doing more async work first

Comment: Rust/tokio async is non-preemptive, so interleaving is not a problem. Is there some kind of `wait` in your `loop`, or does it run with 100% cpu power?

Comment: @Finomnis that's not the way `async` is supposed to work in Tokio, but `poll` could still be used to do what the OP is describing.

Comment: For more context, the purpose of the queue is something like a sequencer - to establish a total ordering over all events, so e.g. I can dump events to a file and easily replay.

Comment: I'd like the loop to run with 100% cpu power, my understanding is that while atypical for many applications, this is best practice for minimizing latncy.

Comment: @yoyoy how it the queue filled? I.e. where do the items put in the queue come from? Some other thread, or one of the `async` tasks?

Comment: one of the async tasks - e.g. imagine the queue is a circular buffer of byte arrays, and several websocket subscriptions write received messages to those byte arrays

Comment: In that case, what's wrong with your last code example? It's a little unorthodox, but it should work ...

Comment: well, `local.poll()` isn't a method that exists - what should I write in its place that does exist?

Comment: [`local.poll`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/struct.LocalSet.html#method.poll) is a method that exists.

Comment: ah but it requires a context argument - how do I construct an appropriate context?

Comment: Not only that - it requires `local` to be pinned as well. There's ways to construct a dummy context. But to be honest, this all goes very deep into a territory that you don't really want to go into, because it feels like we are abusing tokio/async for things it's not meant for. If you use one of the async tasks to fill the queue, what's wrong with using another async task to consume the queue? That's how it is intended by tokio.

Comment: Yeah that might be fine, although it's not clear to me whether it incurs any overhead. It's quite possible I'm trying to translate concepts from C++ that don't have sensible analogues in rust. Thank you for your help!

Comment: This kind of low latency you are hunting for here isn't really achievable in normal operating systems anyway - you would need an RTOS for that, like [`RTIC`](https://rtic.rs). And then, you don't use busy waiting for prioritization - you use priorities instead. That's at least my opinion. In normal operating systems you will get a temporal jitter of several milliseconds purely from the OS scheduler already. Be aware that scheduling overhead of green threads like tokio's tasks is **much** smaller than OS thread scheduling overhead.

Comment: Of course, like always, take everything I say here with a grain of salt and benchmark instead. Especially if your latency requirements are so strict, you absolutely need to benchmark whatever solution you come up with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If:

- All the processing is to be done on a single thread,
- You have `async` tasks that push messages to a queue,
- Processing messages from the queue must take precedence over the pushing tasks.

Then you can probably achieve what you want with [`tokio::select`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.32.0/tokio/macro.select.html)'s [biased](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.32.0/tokio/macro.select.html#fairness) mode, putting the queue processing first:

```
use tokio::sync::mpsc;

async fn push_events (id: i32, tx: mpsc::Sender<(i32, i32)>) {
    for i in 0..10 {
        println!("Task #{id} sending {i}");
        tx.send ((id, i)).await.unwrap();
        tokio::task::yield_now().await;
    }
}

#[tokio::main (flavor = "current_thread")]
async fn main() {
    let (tx, mut rx) = mpsc::channel (1);
    
    let task0 = push_events (0, { let tx = tx.clone(); tx });
    let task1 = push_events (1, { let tx = tx.clone(); tx });
    tokio::pin!(task0);
    tokio::pin!(task1);
    
    loop {
        tokio::select!{
            biased;
            Some ((id, i)) = rx.recv() => {
                println!("Received {i} from task #{id}");
            },
            _ = &mut task0 => {},
            _ = &mut task1 => {},
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=45e87ee8f3810e7ee78bd356966dec77)

Note how the messages are processed immediately, whereas if you comment the `biased` on line 22, then the sending tasks may try to push multiple messages to the queue before they are processed.